# Is there a way of searching YouTube for videos with captions in specific languages?

Tags: youtube, subtitles

I know about using the "cc" operator, as in:

```
Monkeys, cc
```

but what if I only want videos about Monkeys with Vietnamese (soft-coded) subtitles?

I've tried `cc=vi`, `cc:vi`... none seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve this is to: (a) use the CC search filter, and then (b) use the new auto-translate feature in which you can translate into any language.

[image]

Comment: Thanks - but isn't this just machine translation? I'm only interested in translations produced by humans...